# jQuery swap image on button click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a block of three divs that when clicked will swap an image.  I have this so far..

```js
 $( ".button1" ).click(function() {
  $(this).attr("src","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=1-on")
 });
 $( ".button2" ).click(function() {
  $(this).attr("src","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=2-on")
 });
 $( ".button3" ).click(function() {
  $(this).attr("src","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=3-on")
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button1">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=1-off">
</div>
<div class="button2">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=2-off">
</div>
<div class="button3">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=3-off">
</div>
```

This isn't working for me, does anybody have an similar example they can point me at?

I am also wanting only one 'on' image to be displayed at a time so the others will switch to off when one is on.

Comment: Is there a div where the image you are swapping will be displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give all the divs the same class, then create a single `click` event, which will toggle the current img on, while turning the others off:

```
$('.button img').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');

  $(this).attr('src', src.replace('-off', '-on'));   //change off to on

  $('img').not(this).attr('src', function(_, src) {  //change on to off
    return src.replace('-on', '-off');
  });
});
```

**Snippet:**

```js
$('.button img').click(function() {
  var src = $(this).attr('src');
  
  $(this).attr('src', src.replace('-off', '-on'));   //change off to on
  
  $('img').not(this).attr('src', function(_, src) {  //change on to off
    return src.replace('-on', '-off');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="button">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=1-off">
</div>
<div class="button">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=2-off">
</div>
<div class="button">
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=3-off">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the parent instead of the img.

Try .class img

for example:

```
$( ".button1 img" ).click(function() {
    $(this).attr("src","https://dummyimage.com/100x100/000000/fff&text=1-on")
});
```

This will select the image and not the parent div.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr(
```

should be

```
$(this).find('img').attr(
```